# How to un-paginate a paginated object by will_paginate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, depagination

@models is a paginated object with gem `[will_paginate][1]`:

```
 @models = @models.page(params[:page]).per_page(50)
```

Then retrieving the ids:

```
id_array = @models.pluck('id')
```

But there are only first 50 ids plucked in `id_array` because @models is paginated. Is there a way to un-paginate the `@models`?

Comment: If your `@models` contains, let say, User records, then use `User.scoped.pluck(:id)` ; If you don't know what `@models` contains, you can use `@models.first.try(:class).try(:pluck, :id)` (the `try` are here to handle when `@models` is empty)

Comment: Works great! Will mark as answer if you post it as answer. BTY what's the purpose of .first?

Comment: Your variable `@models` is an array containing several records. The method `first` called on `@models` (an array) will return the first element of the array (if exist). Then we try to get the class (Model name) of the first element of the array. If we get the class, we call `pluck` with `:id` as argument.

Comment: The way we solve the problem is to set a huge# for paging: `@models = @models.page(params[:page]).per_page(10000).pluck('id')` which un-paginates `@models` in fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that `@models` contains User records:

```
User.scoped.pluck(:id)
```

If you don't know what contains `@models`:

```
@models.first.try(:class).try(:pluck, :id)
```

But the second option will only work if you have at least one record in the `@models` array, also if `@models` contains several Model's records (example: User and Player record), it won't take all IDs of both models but only one.

Comment: MrYshiji, just a little issue as the post may not explain well. variable models itself is a SQL result (subset) on the table.  models.first.try(:class).try(:pluck, :id) select all the records in the table and there are records which are not in variable models being picked up. Is there any way we can retrieve only the records in variable models?

Comment: Yes, you can do `@models.pluck(:id)` but **before** you call `paginate` on it

Answer (score 0):

```
 @models = @models.page(params[:page]).per_page(50)
```

to reset pagination just reset `offset` and `limit`:

```
 @models.offset(0).limit(nil).pluck(:id)
```